# Most performant way to send big buffer in express?

Tags: node.js, express

the code I'm using right now is

```
const bigBuffer = ... // 25MB
routes.get('/path', (req, res) => {
  res.send(bigBuffer)
})
```

it seems rather slow to download, maybe my server is slow? Is there a way to make it download faster? note that my buffer is already in memory so I don't need to stream it or read it from a file.

Comment: Maybe your server is slow yes... You don't give enough info to make this question answerable...

Comment: try to stream it, instead of blowing the TCP connection with 25MB of data.

Comment: _"seems rather slow to download"_ compared to what? how much is the downstream network speed??